# Javascript Threading With Ajax Callbacks

Tags: javascript

Given the following code:

```
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
```

...

```
var storedVal = "";

function taChanged(evt) {
    storedVal = $("#mytext").val();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytext").onkeydown(taChanged);
    doUpdate();
});

function doUpdate() {
    $.ajax("example.com/updates", function() {
        var storedVal1 = storedVal ;

        // lengthy processing here
        // ........

        var storedVal2 = storedVal ;
        var domVal = $("#mytext").val();

        if(storedVal1 != storedVal2) alert("storedVal changed while processing");
        if(storedVal1 != domVal) alert("real val changed while processing");

        doUpdate();
    });
}
```

1. Will the first alert ever show?
2. Will the second alert ever show?
3. Why?

Comment: For answers to 1 and 2...try it and see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from WebWorkers, JavaScript runs in a single thread so even if the presses a key, clicks on an element, or performs any other interaction with the page, the data accessible from JS will not change. In fact, the UI will block until your JS finishes running; only after the interpreter has run all of your JavaScript code does it relinquish control to the browser, which can finally process all of the UI events that have queued up.

Therefore, assuming that your "lengthy processing" does not modify `storedVal`, **the first alert can never show**. There is no opportunity for the user or browser to get the JS interpreter to modify `storedVal`.

**The second alert can never show** as well, assuming that there is no other JS code that modifies `storeVal` or the textarea's value. This remains true in more complex scenarios, where the user types in the textbox after you issue your AJAX request but before the callback function is invoked:

1. The user types in the textarea, your `onkeydown` handler is invoked, you save the value of the textarea in `storedVal`, and then send an AJAX request. The JS interpreter gives back control to the browser.
2. The AJAX request is in flight, and the user types in the textarea, causing the browser to invoke the `onkeydown` handler a second time, thus overwriting `storedVal` with the new value of the textarea and issuing another AJAX request.
3. When the first AJAX response arrives and invokes the AJAX callback, it will compare the new value of `storedVal` with the new value of the textarea, which will be equal.

The key here is that if the only way to modify `$('#mytext').val()` is by typing a key, and if the only code that modifies `storedVal` is `storedVal = $('#mytext').val()`, then the two will always be equal inside of your AJAX callback.

P.S. A small typo (`$('#mytext').val().length()` instead of `$('#mytext').val()`) will cause the program to crash.

Comment: So if the user types in the textarea during length processing, $('#mytext').val() will not change until the entire callback method finishes?

Comment: That's right—the lengthy processing will freeze up the entire UI, so the textarea will not receive the user's keypress (thus your keydown handler will not run, and nor will the pressed key even show up in the text area). After all of your JS completes, then the user might see a flurry of keys appear if they were trying to type and the browser had queued up everything.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is not multi threaded, so, if both coditions in both if's statements are true, both alert will show, in that order.

Comment: Using workers you can get threading, but in his example, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Even with workers, you don't run into multi threading issues, all you can do between workers/main is message passing.